# Remove "/" from the end of a variable

Tags: php, variables, trailing-slash

Can any one please tell me how I can remove the slash from the end of a variable

In my index.php I have the following:

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
include_once "sites/$url.php";
```

My problem is if I write `example.com/test/somefile/` nothing comes but if I write `example.com/test/somefile` it works

So is there a way to remove the slash if the variable ends with a slash?

Comment: [`rtrim($url, '/');`](http://php.net/rtrim)

Comment: you are opening your system to hackers thou. Read up on code injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection

Comment: Consider someone calling not `/index.html` but `/../../../someSystemConfigFile.conf`

Comment: Instead of using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, use something else, like `dirname(__FILE__)` for instance.

Comment: emm. I see my site can get hacked with ease. How can I use the dirname(__FILE__)??

Comment: It's not just `FILE`; there are two underscores surrounding each side: `__FILE__`. It's one of PHP's [magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: (__FILE__) when I write it it dosent show the __ wtf. But how do I use it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
```

From PHP.net https://www.php.net/rtrim

> > 

You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

While this will solve your problem, please take a few minutes to consider the warnings posted in the comments and the other answer(s) regarding [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) since it is a very serious security issue.

Comment: Please take advice regarding code injection and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability

Answer (score 4):

Please do not do this.

You are **relying** on your user being a goody two shoes and not futzing with requests.

In conclusion: **DO NOT** rely on browser requests to include a file in your code